# htaccess rewrite rule for URL

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I want to have a formatted URL like this:

```
www.mysite.com/view.php?id=1
```

where:

```
"id" range: 1-99 (without leading "0" from 1 to 9)
"id": always lowercase, no "Id" or "ID" or "iD"
```

Anything different from this format must redirect it to
**www.mysite.com/view.php** or formatted `ID` value:

Examples:

```
www.mysite.com/view.php?id=1sdeW --> www.mysite.com/view.php?id=1
www.mysite.com/view.php?erwrrw34 --> www.mysite.com/view.php
www.mysite.com/view.php?id=01 --> www.mysite.com/view.php?id=1
www.mysite.com/view.php?ID=33 --> www.mysite.com/view.php?id=33
```

I did some part of this logic already (**RegExp**, **htaccess**, **rewriterules**):

Please, help to complete the full logic above.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ID=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /view.php?id=%1 [R=301,L]
```

## **EDIT #1**

I simplified my approach to achieve the same results:

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/view.php$
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?!(id=[1-9][0-9]{0,1})$).*$
   RewriteRule .* ? [R=301,L]
```

1) With:

```
   RewriteRule .* ? [R=301,L]
```

It works, but the link placed inside of my web page to:

```
   www.mysite.com/view.php
```

also redirects to:

```
   www.mysite.com
```

2) With:

```
   RewriteRule .* /view.php? [R=301,L]
```

I receive well known "TOO MANY REDIRECTS" loop.

How do I get rid of this?

Comment: you can't use "/view/id/9" which will end up: "/view/id/([0-9]+)/?$" and have a rule that redirects to /view.php if that does not match the first one?

Answer (score 1):

The main thing is to make sure that you handle only URLs that starts with `/view.php`. Next, when you use `RewriteRule` there is no need to capture the URL using `^(.*)$`. Finally, divide the logic into smaller handlers.

```
# Correct the wrong case for the "id" parameter
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/view.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (ID|Id|iD)=(\d+)
RewriteRule . /view.php?id=%2 [R=301,L]

# Make sure that "id" contains only digits
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/view.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([1-9]\d*)[^&]+
RewriteRule . /view.php?id=%1 [R=301,L]

# Check if the current URL contains "view.php?" but doesn’t have a valid "id" string
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s+/view.php\?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(id=[1-9])
RewriteRule . /view.php? [R=301,L]
```